# Setting multiple attributes with .attr()

Tags: jquery, load, src, attr

I'm having a function here:

**EDIT :** gave you full code here!

```
$(".thumbnail").live("click",
    function(){
    $('#imageBig').find("#pictureContainer").remove();

    $('#loadingImage').fadeIn();

    var path = $(this).children().attr("src");
    var newPath = path.substring(0, path.length-9);
    var newPath2 = newPath += ".jpg";

    var imageLoad = new Image();

    $(imageLoad).load(function () {
        if (--imageLoad == 0) {
            // ALL DONE!
        }
        // anything in this function will execute after the image loads
        $('#loadingImage').fadeOut();
        var newImg = $('<img />').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
        newImg.css("height","400px").css("width","600px");
        $('#imageBig').append( $(newImg) );
    })
    .attr({
        src:newPath2,
        id:"pictureContainer"
    });
})
```

My problem is with the .attr()

When loading the image, it does change the src (so line 1 "`src:newPath2`" works), but it doesn't put the id. So when my image is created, it only does : `<img src="newpath2" />`. No id. Am I doing something wrong? I checked the jquery documentation a few times and i'm pretty sure that's how to do it.

I think the problem comes with the .load() but i'm not sure what doesn't work.

Thank you!

(if you need it, I can give you the code before that)

**SOLVED :**

Just have to give the id to newImg instead of imageLoad.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to set the id on #imageBig?

Comment: What is `imageLoad`? Why are you decrementing it?

Comment: is newPath2 a variable in your code?

Comment: I gave you the full code before. sorry my bad!

Comment: @kinakuta: No, I created a new image and just want to add the id pictureContainer to it. I added the code before. It's more clear now!

Comment: You are decrementing an Image object... maybe that could be the cause. Try to comment that if statement to see what happens.

Comment: @SLaks: I copied the code from a tutorial website. I removed it from the my code. Works as good as before. hehe.

Comment: @valipour: yes, added the code before!

Comment: @Jose Faeti: I tried removing it, works like before.

Comment: Anyway I don't see the point in having two different new images.. you are appending newImg, but then what about imageLoad you created before?

Comment: I think you should give the ID to $newImage.

Comment: @Jose Faeti: Wow... easy as that. I gave the id to newImage. It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newImg has the same SRC because of `$('<img />').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'))`, but not the same ID, then I think you are appending (and referring to) newImg, so you should give the ID to newImg instead of loadImage.

Comment: I tried your first solution. Doesn't work either! It does the same exact thing. But I find it strange that via .attr(), it gets the src attribute, but not the second.

Comment: newImg has the same SRC because of $('<img />').attr('src',$(this).attr('src')), but not the same ID, then I think you are appending (and referring to) newImg, so you should give the ID to newImg instead of loadImage.

Comment: Yes! It worked thank you! You might want to edit your answer so I can accept it. You've have been a great help helping me realize this simple error.

Comment: That's it! Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 1):

Setter and Getter!

```
(function($) {
    // Attrs
    $.fn.attrs = function(attrs) {
        var t = $(this);
        if (attrs) {
            // Set attributes
            t.each(function(i, e) {
                var j = $(e);
                // Aplica atributos
                for (var attr in attrs) {
                    j.attr(attr, attrs[attr]);
                };
            });
            return t;
        } else {
            // Get attributes
            var a = {},
                r = t.get(0);
            if (r) {
                r = r.attributes;
                for (var i in r) {
                    var p = r[i];
                    if (typeof p.nodeValue !== 'undefined') a[p.nodeName] = p.nodeValue;
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Use:

```
// Setter
$('#element').attrs({
    'name' : 'newName',
    'id' : 'newId',
    'readonly': true
});

// Getter
var attrs = $('#element').attrs();
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit confused by what you are trying to do but why not just do:

```
var newImg = $('<img />').attr('src',$(this).attr('src')).attr('id',$(this).attr('id'));
```

Wouldn't that give you the id as well?